# Помощь по настройке секунд RTC. Спешат секунды RTC на STM32F103C8Tx?

Tags: stm32, электроника

Всем привет! Возникла проблема: спешат RTC секунды на STM32F103C8Tx. Засёк секундомером - на 53-54 итерирует минуту, как можно исправить, что бы итерировало на 59?

Настройки RTC от CubeMX (внешний кварц включен):

```
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = RTC_AUTO_1_SECOND;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUTSOURCE_ALARM;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Настройки тактового сигнала:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC;
  PeriphClkInit.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSI;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_RCC_EnableCSS();
}
```

Comment: Покажите настройки тактового сигнала.

Comment: @maestro добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете тактирование часов реального времени от внутреннего низкочастотного RC-генератора. Согласно документации, часы могут тактироваться от HSE/128, от внешнего часового кварца, или от внутреннего RC-генератора (смотри рисунок).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало быть, вам надо просто переключить его на HSE/128 (или часовой кварц, если он у вас есть).

```
PeriphClkInit.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSI;
```

Вот в этой строчке поменяйте источник тактирования.

Второй вариант - использовать калибровку LSI. Но это сложнее, и почти никто этого не делает.

Comment: Спасибо! Поставил на RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_HSE_DIV128, всё работает. За одно исправил проблему с сбиванием часов после отключения питания к MCU